# Error -2 with Tensorflow when using .fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error when I am trying to fit the model.
[image]

I thought something must have gone wrong and I tried again on fresh install of Windows 10.
I want tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0, so first installed Anaconda, CUDA 10.0, its CuDNN, inside Anaconda prompt,
`pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0` and `pip install opencv-python`.

And still the problem persists. I have checked the list of devises and yes it shows my GPU. I even tried with normal tensorflow, same issue again.

Below is the entire code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#importing tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Input,Conv2D,MaxPool2D,Activation,Dropout,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
import random as rn
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook,tqdm
import random
from tensorflow.keras.initializers import he_normal,glorot_normal,he_uniform
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL import Image
import datetime
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
#%load_ext tensorboard
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
# from keras_tqdm import TQDMNotebookCallback
# import pydot

df = pd.read_csv('labels_final.csv')

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(df['path'], df['label'], test_size = .2,random_state =42)

train_labels_df = pd.concat([train_x_filenames,train_y], axis=1)
test_labels_df = pd.concat([test_x_filenames, test_y], axis = 1)
train_labels_df.columns=['filename','label']
test_labels_df.columns = ['filename','label']
test_labels_df['label']=test_labels_df['label'].map(lambda x: [x])
train_labels_df['label']=train_labels_df['label'].map(lambda x: [x])


###Image data Generator class
ImageFlow = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.,validation_split=0.25)
test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
##We are fitting the data to Image data generator.

train_ImageGenerator = ImageFlow.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train_labels_df,
directory="train_assignment/",
x_col="filename",
y_col='label',
subset="training",
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(256,256))

test_ImageGenerator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=test_labels_df,
directory="test_assignment/",
x_col="filename",
y_col='label',
batch_size=32,
seed=42,
shuffle=True,
class_mode="categorical",
target_size=(256,256))

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

## Set the random seed values to regenerate the model.
np.random.seed(0)
rn.seed(0)

input_layer = Input(shape=(256,256,3), name='Input_Layer')

# VGG 16
vgg_16_model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)(input_layer)

# Assignment Layers Model #1
model_1_layer_1_conv = Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(3,3), strides= (1,1)
               , padding = 'valid'
               , data_format = 'channels_last'
               , activation = 'relu'
               , kernel_initializer = he_uniform(seed=40)
               , name = 'Assignment_Conv_1')(vgg_16_model)

model_1_layer_1_pooling = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),name='Assignment_Pooling_1',data_format='channels_last')\
        (model_1_layer_1_conv)

model_1_flat = Flatten(data_format='channels_last',name='Flatten')(model_1_layer_1_pooling)

fc_1 = Dense(units=1000,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed=3),name = 'FC1')(model_1_flat)

fc_2 = Dense(units=500,activation='relu',kernel_initializer=he_uniform(seed=5),name = 'FC2')(fc_1)

output_layer = Dense(units=16,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=30),name = 'Output')(fc_2)


model_1 = Model(inputs= input_layer, outputs = output_layer)

model_1.layers[1].trainable = False # Freeze the vgg layer

# Tensoboard
model_logs = 'tensor_board_logs\\final_model_logs\\' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
tensorboard_callback_1 = TensorBoard(log_dir=model_logs, histogram_freq=1, write_graph = True, write_grads= True)

model_1.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_1.fit(x=train_ImageGenerator,steps_per_epoch=900, epochs=3)
```

And this is the error message I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8cc464c2e1c9> in <module>
----> 1 model_1.fit(x=train_ImageGenerator,steps_per_epoch=900, epochs=3)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    222           validation_data=validation_data,
    223           validation_steps=validation_steps,
--> 224           distribution_strategy=strategy)
    225 
    226       total_samples = _get_total_number_of_samples(training_data_adapter)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_training_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, steps_per_epoch, validation_split, validation_data, validation_steps, shuffle, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    545         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    546         workers=workers,
--> 547         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    548     val_adapter = None
    549     if validation_data:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py in _process_inputs(model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, sample_weights, class_weights, shuffle, steps, distribution_strategy, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    604       max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    605       workers=workers,
--> 606       use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    607   # As a fallback for the data type that does not work with
    608   # _standardize_user_data, use the _prepare_model_with_inputs.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, **kwargs)
    603       return tuple(None for _ in t.shape)
    604 
--> 605     peek = x[0]
    606     nested_dtypes = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t.dtype, peek)
    607     nested_shape = nest.map_structure(dynamic_shape_like, peek)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
     63         index_array = self.index_array[self.batch_size * idx:
     64                                        self.batch_size * (idx + 1)]
---> 65         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
     66 
     67     def __len__(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    228                            color_mode=self.color_mode,
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,
--> 230                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
    231             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    232             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    117     elif color_mode == 'rgb':
    118         if img.mode != 'RGB':
--> 119             img = img.convert('RGB')
    120     else:
    121         raise ValueError('color_mode must be "grayscale", "rgb", or "rgba"')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in convert(self, mode, matrix, dither, palette, colors)
    871         """
    872 
--> 873         self.load()
    874 
    875         if not mode and self.mode == "P":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in load(self)
   1068     def load(self):
   1069         if self.use_load_libtiff:
-> 1070             return self._load_libtiff()
   1071         return super().load()
   1072 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in _load_libtiff(self)
   1180 
   1181         if err < 0:
-> 1182             raise OSError(err)
   1183 
   1184         return Image.Image.load(self)

OSError: -2
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you expect anyone to magically know what the problem is? You didn't even post the error message.

Comment: can you please send more of your code and the error.

Comment: I have added my entire code and error message I am getting. Please help me out of this situation. The most worrisome is I am getting this even after fresh windows install.

Comment: Could you fetch some images from the train datagenerator and plot?

Comment: I didnt get what you were asking ? I want me to post a sample image from train data ?
Please note that it was working fine few days ago now even after refresh the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same thing -- in my case, it was an image in my training set that PIL could not deal with.  My images were supposed to be all grayscale tif images, but some in the training set were 8-bit-per-pixel gray, some were 16-bit-per-pixel gray, some were 32-bit LZW compressed.   One or more formats caused the error.  I didn't really track it down totally -- instead I went back to the system that generates my train images and modified that code to always output them uniformly (as 8-bit-per-pixel gray uncompressed TIFF).  Then, this issue went away for me.